# How to display Google listing without reviews

Tags: seo, google, google-places

We have a customer who has very old historic bad reviews and has not looked to get recent ones. Can anyone advise how I get Google to display a company as per how the listing looks in the screenshot below? i.e. it does not show their star rating on the right column until I click on the offices listed on the left. Is it achieved by adding multiple branches to an account? Or as some form of brand page?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can't.   According to [How to Remove Bad Reviews from Google Search Engine](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-remove-bad-reviews-from-google-search-engine-sixth-technologies), Google will not remove reviews unless you serve them with a court order.

It would be much easier to have your client solicit newer reviews from loyal customers.